# Change image by Image Sequence in Shader Editor every nth frame

Tags: node-editor

I'm trying to make a video, where I'm using 40 images as an object color possibilities. But when I'm using Image Sequence, the image will change every next frame. But I would like to change each image every sixth frame. Nothing that I found here doesn't help me. Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I found a solution by keyframing the offset property.
[image]

0 at frame 1, 10 at frame 100 and it seems to be moving slowly enough.

Kind of a hack though.

Comment: [#KisKit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/39340/kiskit) has right. Everything is about playing with keyframing and offset and it works well. Thank you so much.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQLYU.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQLYU.jpg)